# display timer for every page starting from(00sec) in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, timer

I created a quiz application using PHP. In that application I display one question per page. When user clicks on the next button, it displays the next question, one chosen randomly from database. So for that I want to display time.

But my problem is:

I want to display a timer from starting only seconds. When user clicks on the next button, first question timer is going to be stored in database and the timer will start(from 00:00) for the second question.

I tried a lot, but I don't have any idea how to do this.

Comment: Maybe post some code of what you have tried or better create a snippet

Comment: update the question don't post code in comment it is unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use window.setInterval() in order for the timer to not rely on the system time. .setInterval will fire every n milliseconds. You can just increment using that

You can have:

```
var secondsCounter = 0;

function quizTimer(){
secondsCounter++;
}

window.setInterval(quizTimer, 1000);
```

Then you can display the time easily by using

```
myTimerElement.innerHTML = "Seconds Passed: " + secondsCounter;
```

Now you just have to do a little tweaking to make it appear in time format MM:SS

it could be

```
myTimerElement.innerHTML = minutesCounter + " : " + secondsCounter;
```

now just do some formatting methods or conditions to make the counter variables display two digits.

EDIT:

Check this snippet:

```js
var secondsCounter = 0;
var startTime;

function restartTimer(){
  secondsCounter = 0;
  window.clearInterval(startTime);
  startTime = window.setInterval(quizTimer, 1000);
}

function quizTimer(){
secondsCounter++;
document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = "Seconds Passed: " + secondsCounter;
}


document.getElementById('btnsub').addEventListener('click', restartTimer);
```

```html
<span id='timer'></span>
<button id='btnsub'>Submit</button>
```

Comment: is the timer start from starting for every page when user click on next button

Comment: You can just fire the script again when loading a new page, since the timer will always become initialised to 0

Comment: can you please explain  it briefly i can't understand

Comment: Every time this script is loaded on a new page, the secondsCounter variable will always become initialised to 0, therefore it will start a new timer from 0. I think you already did the same thing, but I have posted this answer seconds earlier than your edit

Comment: Are you sure you have referenced the script on all your quiz pages?

Comment: i have only one page that is questions.php..in that page only i wrote timer code..questions will be display only one per page  randomly from datbase..so for that one i use next button when user click on next button i display next question..so i want to  dipslay timer for each question l want to know the user how long stay in the question..same thing for second question also when user click on 2nd one the timer should be start form 0

Comment: If you only have one question per page, you shouldn't have any problems. If your questions are scripted, initialise the variable back to 0 on submit button using addEventListener

Comment: can you please show me in snippet..because i tried a lot for the past one week it dosen't work for me..thank you

Comment: i have another doubt..in this, time starts only when we click on the submit  button..but i need time will start automatically for the first time when i dipslay question1...because i display questions depend on the category from another page..

Comment: Yes, you can just modify the code make it fire after the questions are loaded

Comment: or easily, if you are strictly page-based. Just reference the code on each php page so that the timer will start from 0 when each page are loaded

Comment: but in my application page is not refreshed with out refresh only i display next question

Comment: put your script on an external script and reference using <script src="script.js"></script>.